# Crashlytics Generate Symbols task got stuck

Tags: android, crashlytics

Trying to Generate symbols for crashlytics using

```
./gradlew crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug.
```

But this process get stuck, even with --debug there is no logs.
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Where it get stuck? Can you post your console log?

Comment: Can you also share the output from the crashlytics.log file after you run the command? On Linux / Windows: ~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.logOn Mac:~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log Make sure you remove your API key from the output before sharing on here.

Comment: I had a similar issue just a couple of days ago. I believe it's due to the new Fabric plugin tool. So if you were using an open ended version (as suggested by them), try using a specific version:
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+' to classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.5' for example. That's the version I changed to get it working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same problem happened to me today when trying to build a release APK of a project I work on.
Like Alkaiser mentioned, it seems to be a problem with the Fabric tools.

Just open the following URL to see the available Fabric tool versions:
https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

And then go to the project level Gradle file, and change the **io.fabric.tools classpath** to use an earlier version - 1.24.2 should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. This was a bug introduced in 1.24.3 of the Fabric Gradle plugin. It's been fixed in 1.24.4.